# Select only rows with max date

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

In clickhouse table I have multiple rows for one `_id`. What I want is to get only one row for each `_id` where column `_status_set_at` has its max value. 
That's what I am currently at:

```
SELECT _id, max(_status_set_at), count(_id)
FROM pikta.candidates_states
GROUP BY _id
```

[image: output]

Because I can't use `max()` function at `WHERE` clause, how to workaround this problem?
`count(_id)` shows how many rows are there for each `_id`, if the query is correct, it should show 1.
Also, as far as I concerned, there is no `ON` clause in Clickhouse database.

UPD: there is `ON` clause in Clickhouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns what you need - only one row for each _id where column _status_set_at has its max value.
You do not need to change anything in your original query.

count(_id) shows how many rows for each _id in the original table, but not in a query result. 
Query result has only one row for each _id because you group by _id.

This query shows that in your query result there is only one row for each _id

```
SELECT _id, max_status_set_at, count(_id) FROM (
SELECT _id, max(_status_set_at) max_status_set_at
FROM pikta.candidates_states
GROUP BY _id) t
GROUP BY _id
```

If you need apply a condition on max(_status_set_at) you can use HAVING

Answer (score 2):

Solution - 1 :

```
SELECT Z._id,
       Z._status_set_at
  FROM 
(
SELECT _id, 
       _status_set_at, 
       max(_status_set_at) OVER ( PARTITION BY _id ORDER BY _status_set_at DESC ) AS rnk
FROM pikta.candidates_states
) Z
WHERE Z.rnk = 1;
```

Solution - 2 :

```
SELECT A._id,
       A._status_set_at  
  FROM pikta.candidates_states A
CROSS JOIN
       ( 
         SELECT _id, 
                MAX(_status_set_at) AS max_status_set_dt         
           FROM pikta.candidates_states
         GROUP BY _id
        ) B
WHERE A._id = B._id
  AND A._status_set_at = B.max_status_set_dt;
```

Comment: I guess, partition and over is also not implemented in Clickhouse

Comment: He says 
> there is no ON clause in Clickhouse database

Comment: @Teja no. There is only ALL/ANY OUTER/INNER JOIN

Comment: Second solution is pretty close to what I want, but some _id's still get multiple values. https://imgur.com/a/Ofm6rGq

Comment: Is cross join returning any results or throwing an error?

Comment: @Teja ```Error running query: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))```

Comment: @Teja found out, that multiple rows are returned because of some of its _status_id's could also repeat. Its clickhouse's problem, because it does'nt support millseconds. Thanks a lot

Comment: Good. So its not the problem with cross join then.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to you your max clause on where statement maybe this will work

```
SELECT * from (SELECT _id, max(_status_set_at) as [MaxDate], count(_id) as [RepeatCount]
    FROM pikta.candidates_states
    GROUP BY _id) t WHERE t.MaxDate = '@parameter'
```

Answer (score 2):

in clickhouse，this will work

```
select _id, argMax(<col you need>, _status_set_at) from pikta.candidates_states group by _id;
```

[argMax](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/argmax/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<other columns>` with list of other columns you need to select.

```
SELECT _id, _status_set_at, <other columns>
FROM pikta.candidates_states
WHERE (_id, _status_set_at) in (
    SELECT _id, max(_status_set_at)
    FROM pikta.candidates_states
    GROUP BY _id
)
```

Internal select returns pairs of `_id` with max `_status_set_at` for that `_id`. External select returns rows with additional colums from table, but only those of them, where `_id` and `_status_set_at` are in result of internal select, i.e. with max `_status_set_at` for each `_id`.

I posted my reply, because none of previous answers was good for initial question, as I understood it. Request in question should be able to return other colums, not only `_id` and `_status_set_at`, otherwise it's useless, you can use basic select for it, that already was mentiond in question. Mike's answer can't be modified that way. Solutions of Teja won't work in Clickhouse.